# Can i link my web service to azure to receive notification

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hello guys i have a web service that provide informations and i want to receive notitfications when something changes 
do i need to link my web service to azure, and how 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

> do i need to link my web service to azure

**Suggestion:** It depends on your logic in project.You can use the push background of your platform alone to post notifications, or you can use the *Azure Push Notification Hub* to post notifications.

1. Azure Push Notification Hub

Not sure what type of back-up you are.If have a .NET back-end project, it is recommended to look at these documents first.

Here is an official document about [Adding push notifications to your Xamarin.Forms app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push).

And you also need to read this document about [Azure Push Notification Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/push-notifications/azure).

> Azure Notification Hubs provide a scalable push infrastructure for sending mobile push notifications from any backend to any mobile platform, while eliminating the complexity of a backend having to communicate with different platform notification systems. This article explains how to use Azure Notification Hubs to send push notifications from an Azure Mobile Apps instance to a Xamarin.Forms application.

2. Platform Alone

**Android** :If using FireBase to push notification in Android, [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging) providing to push notification in cloud.

**IOS** :IOS using APNS to push notification.[Push Notifications in iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/remote-notifications-in-ios)

**UWP**: [Add push notifications to your Windows app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-push)

In addition, iOS and Android platforms should pay attention to some configurations of their respective platforms when implementing push.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Azure Notification Hub Endpoint and Name in your web service. On required transaction, Service will be send message to Azure.

Same endpoint and hub name will be configured in mobile app. Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.Android and Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.iOS packages will provide access to register, Unregister using NotificationHub class.